# Different App versions in one APK

Tags: android, apk, google-play

This is my problem:
I have an application that requires a certain persmission (Write-SMS) that will of course only function on phones. Now, the app requires that permission for a feature that will be disabled on tablet versions but it won't let users install the app on tablets.

I guess my question is this:

1. Can I easily create a second manifest for the tablet version, that will be roughly the same as the phone version but without the persmission?
2. If I'm doing so, is there a way to check what manifest version is being used? I might want to add features to the tablet version that are tablet exclusive and vice versa.

All of course preferibly in one apk, that gets exported and signed **once**. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

To your manifest. The SMS permission automatically asks for a Telephony feature. Adding this tells android that even though you ask for this feature, you don't need it.

Be sure to add an if-else check to see if you can sens SMS from the device before doing so.

Comment: Okay this is awesome. I didn't know about this! And Eclipse failed to bring it up in the content assist :( I already have the if-else check at the feature itself notifying the user that the feature is available on tablets. It runs on my debug Nexus7 anyways ;)

Comment: @AreusAstarte Welcome! You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check it in the actual method itself, because permissions can be optional or compulsory, but that's it, not distinguishable for different devices..